# How to display images from json URL when the images key has two object values

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

This is my first stackoverflow post....be kind

I am building a react app where I want to display an image from a array of objects but the "images:" object has two objects inside example:

```
 [
  { value: "all", label: "All sets" },
  {
    value: "base1",
    label: "Base",
    series: "Base",
    printedTotal: 102,
    total: 102,
    legalities: { unlimited: "Legal" },
    ptcgoCode: "BS",
    releaseDate: "1999/01/09",
    updatedAt: "2020/08/14 09:35:00",
    images: {
      symbol: "https://images.pokemontcg.io/base1/symbol.png",
      logo: "https://images.pokemontcg.io/base1/logo.png",
    },
  },]
```

my question is how would I access the inner object to display just the "logo:" object?

my assumption is to use  a combination of .map and Object.keys() but I'm unsure how to do it.

mycode is below...

````
import React from "react";
import setOptions from "../data/sets";

export default function SetOverview() {
  const sets = setOptions;

  return (
    <div>
      {sets.map((set) => {
        return (
          <div key={set.value}>
            <h2>{set.label}</h2>;<p>Number of cards: {set.printedTotal}</p>
            <p>Release date: {set.releaseDate}</p>
          </div>

        //   image to be placed here 
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );```
````

Comment: `images` will always be the single object not array of objects right? If yes then you can use [js chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `set?.images?.logo`

Comment: have you tried `<img src={set.images.logo}/>` ?

Comment: @Usama you are a legend! this worked, I tried chaining without the question marks, can you explain why they are needed?

Comment: [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) can be used to prevent `null or undefined` error. Like in your first object there is not `images` object so if you write `values.image.logo` without `?`, In some cases this can cause error because there is no `images` object to get logo value, so `set.images?.logo` will work

Answer (score 0):

ma friend. Welcome to Stack Overflow, and no- you will not be treated with kindness. That being said,
If you are sure about the keys that are being passed in the dataset, i.e.: objName.objItem.`images.logo`, then all you need to do is,

1. Check if the images key exists in that object (because your first object doesn't have it, so I suspect there may be a reason for that).
2. Load the image's logo value inside that `div` you've specified.

To achieve this, all you need to do is:
`set.images?.logo && <img src={set.images.logo} />`
And voila, you shall have your image. The question mark checks if key exists.